# Can I get some verification or help showing this curve can or cannot be used for square wheels?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

I was trying to work out a single portion of a curve necessary for a stable square wheel. I was trying to do this with trigonometry only, which I wasn’t sure how possible this was to begin with, but I believe I found a curve that works. For a square of side length “s”, the following expression should keep the center of the square at a constant height and thus be a “road” for a square wheel:

$\frac{s\sqrt{2}}{2}(1-\frac{1}{\sin{(\frac{x\sqrt{2}}{s})}+\cos{(\frac{x\sqrt{2}}{s})}})$

For

$0\leq x\leq \frac{s\pi \sqrt{2}}{4}$

Which represents the curve for a quarter turn of the square. I calculated the maximum distance from the center of the square and the perimeter. I then calculated the distance between the center and all other points in the form of a function in polar form, and then used the curve to keep the total distance from the surface to the center constant for all angles within a quarter turn (since it will repeat itself after that point). Can someone verify if this curve will work?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I edited it. Im typing this out at almost 2 am. I meant expression and its supposed to represent one of the curves of a road a square wheel could be stable on relative to the ground.

Comment: One obvious problem is that the distance along the curve for a "quarter turn" is greater than $s.$

Comment: I thought about this, and I thought about it like a square inscribed in a circle. The expression above represents the distance between the square and the outer circle at any given point and since we are assuming the ground is flat, this circle can roll stable along the ground and a quarter turn of this square is equal to a quarter of the arc length of this circle.

Comment: Its possible I did something wrong, but thats why I am here actually, I would like help attempting this.

Comment: Does the distance between endpoints need to be equal to the side length?

Comment: What mechanism turns the wheel and moves the axle forward in perfect synchronization so that the wheel is always contacting the right spot on the "road"? Usually for something called a wheel, we expect that mechanism to be static friction between the wheel and the road, that is, the wheel doesn't slip, so the path length along the road between two points is equal to the path length between the points on the wheel that contact the road.

Comment: This seems to be the week for polygonal wheels on specialized roads: [How can I get the exact function for the catenaries](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4634387/139123)